# PFQuery GROUP BY alternative

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, pfquery

I need a parse/obj-c alternative preferably server side or client side (iOS) to GROUP BY function in sql.

I understand that there is no GROUP BY function in parse. On SQL I would execute:

```
select count(*), name, organization from table GROUP BY name
```

And I would get the number of entries for each unique name.

Since I cant do that on Parse, I am stuck after querying the table.

I have an NSArray whose objects are NSDictionaries which I can access by [valueforKey:@"name"] etc

```
Name Organization
a    b    
a    b
a    b
c    d
c    d
```

I need a result table such as

```
Name Organization Count
a    b            3 
c    d            2
```

Is it possible at all on parse? If not how can I get this done on obj-c?

Comment: In iOS, you *could* put this in a SQLlite database and execute your count/groupby query on that.  This is probably overkill though.  In what format do you get the data in Objective-C?  Is it an array of dictionaries with column names as keys, each dictionary representing a row?

Comment: I am sure there is a simpler way than creating another local database. But thanks for the input. I have an NSArray whose objects are NSDictionaries which I can access by [valueforKey:@"name"] etc

Comment: I suggest to keep a new table with that informations. Let's suppose we could have a new table called "OrganizationCount" that have a pointer column to the "Organization" table (eg: refOrg) and a numeric column (eg: "orgCount"). So you could increase / decrease "orgCount" each time it is necessary in your app / service for each specific organization, and select all including also that count field. Obviously this take sense if you don't have any kind of filter, but simply consider all your organizations